# I've got this error message from strip: [.gnu.build.attributes]: corrupt GNU build attribute note: wrong note type: bad value

Tags: linux, g++, fedora, strip

I'm creating an rpm package for my c++ program on Fedora 31. I've already created a .deb package on Debian 10 without issues, but on Fedora 31, when I use the shell command:

```
strip --strip-unneeded --remove-section=.comment --remove-section=.note ttxtgm
```

I get this error message:

> strip:ttxtgm[.gnu.build.attributes]: corrupt GNU build attribute note:
>   wrong note type: bad value

I can't understand what is the problem with this executable.
I use g++ to build my program.
The same command shell executed on Debian 10 works fine.
I couldn't find any information about this error message from strip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a binutils bug that was recently introduced into Fedora 31:

- [strip:testprog[.gnu.build.attributes]: corrupt GNU build attribute note: wrong note type: bad value](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1767937)

It is being fixed in `binutils-2.32-29.fc31`, with this [binutils update](https://bodhi.fedoraproject.org/updates/FEDORA-2019-8aa040b253). Once it hits the Fedora mirrors, you can install it using:

```
dnf update --enablerepo=updates-testing binutils
```

Before that, you can install the build directly from Koji, from the [binutils-2.32-29.fc31 build](https://koji.fedoraproject.org/koji/buildinfo?buildID=1415570):

```
dnf install https://kojipkgs.fedoraproject.org//packages/binutils/2.32/29.fc31/x86_64/binutils-2.32-29.fc31.x86_64.rpm
```